# Which plugin is better for developing browser tables: jQuery Datatables or AngularJs UI Grid?

Tags: datatables, angular-ui-grid

Here is Google trends statictics. AngularJs is a very popular framework, the UI Grid has lower request rates than jQuery Datatables.

[image]

Which plugin is better today for developing customable browser tables: AngularJs Grid UI or jQuery Datatables?

P.S.: I have already checked that AngularJs Grid UI is the most popular table plugin among all angularjs table plugins (google trends and github statistics is checked). Also I do not like angular datatables plugin because it is not as customable and sometimes not as fast as original datatables.

Comment: If I can make a recommendation : https://github.com/MoonStorm/trNgGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has been around for a very long times and therefore statistics are true with more requests for jquery datatables.

But, the choice depends on you. If your application is angular app and you want to go throughj the angular way, then angular grid ui is the best bet. This takes of the load of refreshing the data. Angular will handle everything for you.
But yes, the library overhead will be there and if you want to put in extra efforts of handling everything on your own , then you can go with jquery datatables.

I would suggest you to go with angular Grid.

Comment: Some not documented drawbacks: 1. column auto-width in a bootstrap modal sometimes does not work, but proper column auto-width triggers when window is resized. 2. three-state sorting is also confusing ('unknown'-third state) by default.

Comment: UI Grid is opensource and that is a great plus.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246402/ui-grid-v0-3-1-column-auto-width-issue-detected

Comment: 3. Can I access UI Grid isolate scope from outside, there is no example in the tutorials.