# UI Grid v3.1.0 column auto width issue detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have found many questions about UI Grid autowidth issue. I managed to reproduce one of them and would like to share with you the details on how to reproduce it.

First, I have the default UI Grid inside of a hidden modal (you can find the code snippet at the end of this post).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the code snippet, press "Launch demo modal"; (there is no issues);
   [image]
2. Close the modal;
3. Resize browser window. here it is. Column width is reset to a wrong value.
   [image]

   ```js
   var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid']);
    
   app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
     $scope.gridOptions1 = {
       enableSorting: true,
       columnDefs: [
         { field: 'name' },
         { field: 'gender' },
         { field: 'company', enableSorting: false }
       ],
       onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
         $scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
       }
     };
    
      
    
    $scope.gridOptions1.data = [
       { name: 1, gender: 2, company: 3 }, 
       { name: 1, gender: 2, company: 3 }, 
       { name: 1, gender: 2, company: 3 }, 
       { name: 1, gender: 2, company: 3 }, 
       { name: 1, gender: 2, company: 3 }];
   }]);
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <link href="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <script src="https://rawgit.com/HubSpot/tether/master/dist/js/tether.js"></script>
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>

   <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.js"></script>




   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Launch demo modal
   </button>

   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body" ng-app="app">
           <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
           <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions1" class="grid"></div></div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Also I would like to share with you an approach of fixing it.

Actually, there are two bugs here.

1. UI Grid is set to 0 on page resize when modal is hidden;
2. UI Grid is set to 0 on page load.

The first one is easy to detect and fix if you use uncompressed version of UI Grid:

> There reason of both issues is the same. The width of hidden element is zero.

A simple workaround with jQuery will be as follows for the first case:

```
// Resize the grid on window resize events
function gridResize($event) {
    grid.gridWidth = $scope.gridWidth = gridUtil.elementWidth($elm);
    grid.gridHeight = $scope.gridHeight = gridUtil.elementHeight($elm);
    console.log(grid.gridWidth);
    console.log(grid.gridHeight);
    if(!$($elm).is(':hidden') && grid.gridWidth > 0) { //add such if statement before                 
        grid.refreshCanvas(true); //this is UI Grid code
    }
}
```

The second case is not so simple to fix. Because we need to get the width of Grid container ( in this case modal is the container ).

Container might be inside of a hidden element ( that means `jQuery(gridContainer).width()` will return zero ).

That is how I came across `jQuery.actual` plugin ([github](https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual/commits/master) or [demo](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/get-hidden-elements-width-and-height-with-jquery/)). I will use it to show you a solution for this specific case:

```
// Initialize the directive
function init() {
    if($($elm).is(':hidden')) { //added
        grid.gridWidth = $scope.gridWidth = $($elm).parent().actual('width'); //added
    }  //added
    else {  //added
        grid.gridWidth = $scope.gridWidth = gridUtil.elementWidth($elm); //this is UI Grid code
    }  //added
}
```

As result we will get a UI Grid with proper auto width feature.
Finally, we do not need `$Interval` workaround from the [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/110_grid_in_modal) with this approach.